# É correto dizer "bastantes"?

Tags: significado, gramática, sintaxe

É comum usarmos a palavra "bastante" como adjetivo.

> Exemplo:
>   Já estudei bastante sobre este assunto.

Podemos flexionar a palavra "bastante" para o plural?

> Exemplo:
>   Existem bastantes formas de fazer isso.

Existe alguma exceção?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Na verdade, o seu primeiro exemplo mostra o uso como advérbio (de intensidade). O segundo mostra mesmo um uso como adjetivo, e nesse caso é sim correto concordar em número com o substantivo a que ele se refere. Aliás, deixar "bastante" no singular estaria errado naquela frase.

Na prática, porém, é muito raro ver alguém usar a concordância correta, mesmo na forma escrita. Não por acaso, os primeiros resultados de uma busca no Google por *bastantes* são justamente perguntas iguais à sua, e não textos em que o termo é usado por outro motivo.

Comment: Eu particularmente, acho estranho "bastantes" como sinônimo de "vários". Pra mim, "bastante" é só advérbio de intensidade.

Answer (score 1):

Regra básica de concordância para a palavra "Bastante" e sua forma plural:

Se na frase em questão for possível a substituição para o advérbio de intensidade "muito", *e este puder ser flexionado no plural (muitos)*, então você DEVE usar o plural bastanteS, caso contrário estará cometendo um erro de concordância.

No primeiro exemplo veja que a fórmula não permite o uso do "bastante**s**", pois o "muito**s**" não encaixa

> Já estudei muito**s** (sic) sobre este assunto

Já no seu segundo exemplo veja que o que foi dito se encaixa perfeitamente:

> Existem muit**as** formas de fazer isso. (Concordência de género e pluralidade no "muito".)

LOGO

> Existem bastante**s** formas de fazer isso. (Logo, concordância também no "bastante".)

Comment: Maximiliano, o perguntador dá dois exemplos. A resposta ficaria melhor se mostrasse a substituição nos dois exemplos.

Comment: Feita a edição.

Comment: Hm, no primeiro exemplo, ao contrário, a substituição pelo advérbio de intensidade "muito" é perfeitamente possível: *Já estudei **muito** sobre esse assunto*. No segundo exemplo, porém, a substituição é impossível: * *Existem **muito** formas de fazer isso*. Se "bastante" é sinônimo do advérbio "muito",  então é advérbio também, e não flexiona. Se "bastante" é sinônimo do **adjetivo** muito/muita/muitos/muitas, então também é adjetivo, e tem singular e plural. -1.

Comment: @LuísHenrique pode-se sempre fazer a substituição, sim. Mas esta resposta diz «se se puder fazer a substituição **e o "muito" puder ser flexionado»... e no primeiro exemplo o "muito" não pode ser flexionado. Não percebo a crítica. Achas que a resposta está pouco clara?

Comment: @ANeves Se pode ser flexionado, então definitivamente não é um advérbio. Advérbios não flexionam (exceto talvez em grau, mas evidentemente não é o caso).